# Checked input doesn't uncheck when pressing other inputs

Tags: html, css

I have three buttons the user can press. By default, I have the first one already pressed because I don't want the user to submit the form without pressing anything. The problem is that in mobile phones, if I press another button that hasn't the attribute of 'checked', it gets pressed normally but the one checked by default is not going away. This works fine in computer but not in mobiles. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```html
<div class="control radio-toolbar" id="duration-picker">
  <div class="control radio-toolbar container fm-radios">
    <div style="display: inline-block" class="fm-radio dib">
      <input checked class="date-button" type="radio" value="1" name="options" id="letter_pick_date_1" />

      <label for="letter_pick_date_1">1 year</label>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block" class="fm-radio dib">
      <input class="date-button" type="radio" value="3" name="options" id="letter_pick_date_3" />
      <label for="letter_pick_date_3">3 years</label>
      <br><br>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block" class="fm-radio dib">
      <input class="date-button" type="radio" value="5" name="options" id="letter_pick_date_5" />
      <label for="letter_pick_date_5">5 years</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also one is above the other one and don't know how to solve this. I displayed them inline but wont work

EDIT: Another thing i could do is to have no default checked inputs. But how do I make this required so that nobody submits the form without pressing the buttons?

Comment: What mobile platform/browser is not working for you? This seems valid to me. (Also, use the CSS `vertical-align: top;` on the inline div to line them up)

Comment: I'm using safari. The vertical align thing worked. Now they are lined up. Thank you

Comment: Testing this in Safari on iOS seems to work correctly for me, could you try opening this question on your device and seeing if it reproduces the problem? If not, it's possible that whatever is causing the problem is not included in the code in the question.

Comment: There might be something wrong with my classes. How would you go about doing the thing i said in my edit?

Comment: Please use different **name** to radio button.

Comment: Here, same name given to this all radio button. So, it will check only one at a time.